# "View As" gone from Visual Studio 2012 Source Control Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS 2010 you were able to select "View As" as a way to open the file in something other than VS (like Dreamweaver).  Is that feature gone?

Comment: I don't see a "View As" option in VS2010.  Do you see this when you right click on a file in the Solution Explorer?  Maybe you had some plug-in installed responsible for this.

Answer (score 2):

You were seeing the 'view as' option in vs2010 because you have tfs power tools installed.  The solution in vs2012 is to install the vs2012 powertools from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).