# How do I configure Visual Studio 2012 to launch an external editor

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'd like to configure Visual Studio 2012 / TFS to launch an external editor when I double click the source file in the Source Control Explorer.

I've seen where I can add an external editor as an External Tool, but don't see how to link that external tool to a particular file extension and to launch when double clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the file in Solution Explorer / Open with / Choose Program / Set as Default

From comments:

> I'm in the Source Control Explorer. I assume I can't do it from there? (I don't see menu options for Open with...).

Or from Source Control Explorer, I have an option "View With" in Visual Studio 2010 that works in the same way.  I don't have it in VS2012, and a comment on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014212/view-as-gone-from-visual-studio-2012-source-control-explorer) suggests it may be provided by an add-in (perhaps TFS power tools, since I don't have any other add-ins installed in VS2010).

It may be that if you click on "Set as Default" from Solution Explorer to set an external tool as editor for a file extension, then this becomes the default for viewing from Source Control Explorer too.  But I haven't tried this.

Comment: I'm in the Source Control Explorer.  I assume I can't do it from there?  (I don't see menu options for Open with...).

Comment: You can't do it from Source Control Explorer. You need to create or open a project, then add the desired file type, if it's not already there.